# How can I scroll to first visible element with a specific div class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Is there anyway to automatically scroll to the first visible element with a certain div class using javascript?

thanks!

Comment: See this stack overflow article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744299/scroll-back-to-the-top-of-div
Try not to re-open previously asked questions.

Comment: The linked question above is similar but not a duplicate of the question asked here.

Answer (score 38):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.class:visible:first').offset().top
}, 1000);
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/xUw54/2/**

Comment: This triggers a JavaScript error if the element does not exist.

Comment: You can simply add something like: " if ($(".class")[0]) { //SCROLL } " to avoid that error

Answer (score 2):

Can be easily done with plain JS:

```
const items = container.getElementsByClassName('active');
const visible = [...items].filter((el) => {
  // jQuery-like :visible selector
  return !!( el.offsetWidth || el.offsetHeight || el.getClientRects().length );
});

if (visible.length > 0) {
  container.scrollTo({
    top: items[0].offsetTop,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

This assumes:

- `container` is your scrollable container, you can replace with `document` & `window` if you're trying to scroll the whole page.
- You're looking for the first item with an `active` class name.
- You'd like a smooth scroll, remove the `behavior: 'smooth'` config if you want the scroll to happen instantly in a single jump.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo

Comment: This is not first visible element. It’s just first element.