# onClick of Button, Scroll the element to top

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to add "ADD COMMENT" button on my page.
So onClick I am showing form to add comment.
I want the form to be scrolled on top position of page, So the user won't need to scroll down to see all comments.

```
<script>function showDiv() {

            var div = document.getElementById('comdiv');
            var button = document.getElementById('button');
            if (div.style.display !== "none") {
                div.style.display = "none";
                button.value = "Add Comments";
            }
            else {
                button.value = "Hide Comments";
                div.style.display = "block";
            }
        }</script>`<input type="button" id="button" name="answer" value="Add Comments" onclick="showDiv()"  autofocus />
    <div id="comdiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >
        <form name="form" id="form" action="" method="post">
            <p class="h5">Comment</p>
            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Write Comment, Max: 140 characters" rows="4"  class="width-50" onblur="checkMe()" ></textarea>
            <span class="forms-desc">Comments should atleast have 20 character's</span><br/>

      <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbutton" class="btn btn-green btn-outline" disabled="disabled">Post Comment</button>
        </form></div>`
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code into your "script" tag

$('#button').click(function() {

```
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 1000);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

in the button add onclick="goTop()"

and define

```
<script>
function goTop(){
formName.submit(); // formName = the name property of the form you are submitting
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollIdIntoView("comment-1"); 
function scrollIdIntoView(id,speed) {
    if ($('#'+id).length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop : $('#'+id).offset().top - 30
        }, speed);
        $('#'+id).show().focus().click();
        return false;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').click(function() {

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: '0px'
  });

});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>
  <li>comment1</li>

</ul>

<button>Comment</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add an ID to your div and use the 'scrollTop' attribute.

Take a look at the following link:

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744299/scroll-back-to-the-top-of-div)

Comment: I did not vote you down. As my reputation is not sufficient.

Comment: I think one of the other guys who answered did it. I am new to Stackoverflow and I didn't know how to format properly, that's probably why they did it.

Comment: It's Okay Geek, Welcome to stackoverflow