# How to make a Back to top link scroll fast to the top instead of instantly jumping

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my page footer I have a "Back to Top" button which instantly jumps to the top of the page. How can I make it so it scrolls fast to the top instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Have you googled this? Many answers already there, you just need to search for them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744299/scroll-back-to-the-top-of-div

Answer (score -1):

you can add these javascript functions:

```
function ScrollTo(name) {
   ScrollToResolver(document.getElementById(name));
}

function ScrollToResolver(elem) {
  var jump = parseInt(elem.getBoundingClientRect().top * .2);
  document.body.scrollTop += jump;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop += jump;
  if (!elem.lastjump || elem.lastjump > Math.abs(jump)) {
    elem.lastjump = Math.abs(jump);
    setTimeout(function() {
      ScrollToResolver(elem);
    }, "100");
  } else {
    elem.lastjump = null;
  }
}
```

and than on the button add this function call:

```
<button onclick="ScrollTo('top')">Back to Top</button>
```

where the very forst element of the content has class "top"